# Is it meaningful to set the timeout on Cypress command to 0?

Tags: testing, web, cypress, e2e-testing

I want to validate the form functionality. I first fill the form with valid data, then I clear the first `input` element and I want to assess that the submit button is disabled.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="time-period-form"] input').eq(1).clear();
cy.get('[aria-label="time-period-submit"]', { timeout: 0 }).should('be.disabled');
```

By default cypress waits 4 seconds for the assessment to be true, so in theory it could happen that my button is enabled for some time (up to 4 seconds) before getting disabled.
I want to prevent this with `timeout: 0` option.

Is this correct?